# Custom post pagination trouble

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I do have a problem with a custom post pagination. I search through this site and googled the whole day yesterday, and found nothing that was similar to what I experience (or I'm getting blind...).

Here is my custom post "recipe":

```
register_post_type( 'recipe', array(
'labels' => array(
    'name'               => __('Recipes'),
    'singular_name'      => __('Recipe'),
    'add_new'            => __('Add New'),
    'add_new_item'       => __('Add new Recipe'),
    'view_item'          => __('View Recipe'),
    'edit_item'          => __('Edit Recipe'),
    'new_item'           => __('New Recipe'),
    'view_item'          => __('View Recipe'),
    'search_items'       => __('Search Recipes'),
    'not_found'          => __('No Recipes found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Recipes found in Trash'),
),
'public'        => true,
'show_ui'       => true,
'hierarchical'  => true,
'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
'menu_position' => 100,
'menu_icon'     => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/icon_recipe.png',
'rewrite'       => array(
    "slug"       => "recipe",
    "with_front" => false,
            "pages"      => true
)
) );
```

I need to load 6 recipes on my recipe page, and then I use jQuery to load the next 6 in AJAX. The code actually grab the "next page" URL (that is hidden in my page) to perform this.

The problem is that it keeps loading the first 6 recipes, despite the fact that the url is correct (/recettes/page/2/).

When I try to load this page directly in the address bar, it redirects to /recettes/ (that is my first page).
Even when I put a die("test") at the top of my template file, it never gets there.
Could it be only related to the URL rewriting?

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The strange thing is that the same mechanism works for the news section...
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Matt

PS: here is the page, if you want to have a look: http://www.francoischartier.ca/recettes/

PPS: and this is the news section that works: http://www.francoischartier.ca/chartier/nouvelles/

---

2013-06-17

I've downloaded the whole site and installed it on my computer (WAMP), and there it works well! But not online. Any idea of what can be wrong? Some of the server's parameter?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: you might also try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I posted there too, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it... The problem was because of a plugin, 404 Redirected.